# SQL regexp query on mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have 1 table named **customer**, there is a field named **custom_id** which contains related data.

```
{"18":["45","48","91"],"20":["82","83",84],"21":["30","31"]}
```

now I want to query the customer who has `"20":["82","83","84"]` in this field.

`"20"`: this part what I want, and the related part my conditions `(82,83,84)`

the result will show if any customer has `"82" or "83" or "84" after "20"`:

how can I query these conditions from this field using regexp.

here is the example:

```
SELECT * FROM `customer` WHERE `custom_id` REGEXP '"20":["82","83","84"]'
```

as you can see if I add [ ] system will not accept it like a string, and also these fields are `(82, 83, 84)` dynamic, anytime I can change it according to query.

thanks in advance.

Comment: You should be using MySQL's JSON support, _not_ regex, here.

Comment: Have your tried escaping the brackets i.e. '"20":\\["82","83","84"\\]'

Answer (score 2):

As Tim Biegeleisen said, you should be using MySQL's JSON support here if you can. One approach would be:

```
SELECT *
FROM customer
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(custom_id, '"82"', '$."20"')
OR JSON_CONTAINS(custom_id, '"83"', '$."20"')
OR JSON_CONTAINS(custom_id, '"84"', '$."20"');
```

However, if your MySQL version doesn't support JSON, you could use `REGEXP` like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM customer
WHERE custom_id REGEXP '"20": ?\\[[^]]*[[:<:]]82[[:>:]]'
OR custom_id REGEXP '"20": ?\\[[^]]*[[:<:]]83[[:>:]]'
OR custom_id REGEXP '"20": ?\\[[^]]*[[:<:]]84[[:>:]]';
```

This regex will match the numbers in any order. It breaks down as follows:

```
"20": ? - literal "20": optionally followed by a single space
\\[     - opening [
[^]]*   - zero or more of anything other than a closing ]
[[:<:]] - opening word boundary (make sure we match entire number)
82      - number to match
[[:>:]] - closing word boundary
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following:

```
SELECT * FROM customer where custom_id regexp '[."20":["82","83","84"].]';
```

and it returned:

`"20":["82","83","84"]`

Check this link for the solution: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d10fd6/3

Comment: when i try to query this the result contains some incorrect informations. {"14":"19","17":"60","18":"67","19":["77","78"],"20":["82","84"],"21":["86"],"23":""}
{"14":"","17":"47","18":"74","19":["77"],"20":["82","84"],"23":""}
{"14":"","17":"47","18":"74","19":["77"],"20":["82","84"],"23":""}
{"14":"","17":"47","18":"70","20":["84"],"23":""}
{"14":"21","17":"57","18":"74","19":["78"],"23":""}
{"14":"15","17":"51","18":"69","19":["76","78"],"23":""}
{"14":"","17":"47","18":"75","19":["80"],"23":""}